# How to access items in binded listbox, wp7

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have XAML for WP7:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbMain" DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtName" Text="{Binding name}" />
                    <ListBox x:Name="lbCars" DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding cars}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel x:Name="spnlCars">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtCarName" Text="{Binding name}" />
                                    <ListBox x:Name="lbCarColor" DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding color}">
                                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <TextBlock x:Name="txtColor" Text="{Binding colorValue}"/>
                                                <Image Name="imgColor"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ListBox>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

My DataContex is set to ViewModel I've created, which is getting data from webservice. Data structure is:

- Machines (has: Vehicles[])
- -Vehicles (has: name, Cars[], Trucks[],...)  ----thats what I'm binding to lbMain
- --Cars (has: name, color[],...) ---- for example, color[0]="red"
- ---colorValue

I also have images resources which I want to put in imgColor.

I don't know hot to:

1. set each imgColor to get different image from resources depending on the txtColor,
2. apply bold font to txtCarName if (for example) txtColor.Text="red".

I appreciate any advice and any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [`Converter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to convert color name into a `BitmapImage`.

Example :

```
class ColorToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        String colorName = (String)value;

        switch (colorName.ToLower())
        {
            case "red":
                return new BitmapImage(new Uri("..."));
            default:
                return new BitmapImage(new Uri("..."));
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great decyclone, thank you! That is the answer I was looking for my first question. 
Any help for my second question? I have a problem when trying to access parent DataContex, and trying to change older ListBoxItem.

Comment: You have to use a converter in the same way, i.e. you bind FontWeight to the color and in the converter you convert Color to FontWeight.

Comment: Well, I agree with Francesco. You just need another converter to convert color name to `FontWeight` type instead of `BitmapImage` type in above example.